# Ubuntu GCC Version error in libgfortran

Tags: linux, ubuntu, administrator, r

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
```

I've just updated R in Ubuntu (using apt-get update / upgrade), however when running R in the console I get the following error:

```
~$ R
/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R: /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.3.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3)
```

Considering GCC 4.3 is pretty old, I'm a bit confused by the error. Does anyone have an explanation / solution that I can try?

Thanks

Comment: Is you libgfortran3 up to date? By browsing the [Ubuntu Package Repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com), it seems that it requires GCC 5.3. Try `sudo apt-get upgrade libgfortran3`.

Comment: Good suggestion, and I did try that. `libgfortran3 is already the newest version (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4).`

Comment: My `libgcc_s.so.1` is in  `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, with another copy in `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` for the 32-bit subsystem. I don't use R, so check if there is a link in the location you cite. If not, check whether `R` is 32- or 64-bit `file $(which R)`, following links if necessary, then create the appropriate link.

Comment: Another good suggestion. `libgcc_s.so.1` is present in both `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` and `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. It seems that someone put a copy of `libgcc_s.so.1`, in `/usr/local/lib/` for a quick fix a long time ago. Removing that file, so that R looked in `/lib/` solved the issue.